# Is it possible to compromise a device by connecting to a database?

Tags: databases, mysql

I have a relatively secure device with very limited internet connections and/or activity. One of those connections is to a AWS RDS database (MySQL)

I'm wondering if it's possible that my secure device could be compromised by this connection if the database were to be compromised.

Comment: Sure, if there was some vulnerability in the database client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a lot of unclear possibilities in your question, but the short answer is "no" with a fairly important "it depends" added to to the answer. If you are saying that your application needs a database for its functionality then there isn't anything inherently vulnerable about adding one to your system. However, every new service that you add will increase the overall attack service:

1. Are you securing your database with strong authentication?
2. Have you gone through the steps to harden/secure your database?
3. Is your database added to your update and patch management workflows?

In addition, if you are using a MySQL database then you need to ensure that whatever application you have connected/leveraging the database is free from any [SQL Injections](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) which can wreck all kinds of havoc on your data, underlying system, or application.

But this is true wisdom of just about anything you want to add to increase something's usefulness. However, managing and securing data is seriously one of the post important parts of information security.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, every external connection is a potential attack vector and should be included in your threat model.

Even if your database isn't compromised, there are ways to use that connection against you. At a minimum, they could cause connections to time out and potentially cause a denial of service. In the worst case, they could trick you into connecting to a less secure database and steal your credentials, then use the credentials to gain further access.

That doesn't mean there isn't an acceptable level of risk with the right mitigations. But if you are trying to maintain an "air-gapped" device of some kind, connecting it to a database is out. It is potentially as dangerous as connecting it to the web.